# connect to sql server 2008 r2 FILESTREAM from remote system

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, blob, filestream, blobstore

I'm developing a online document management application for my client using the following technologies

1. Front End - VB.Net 2010 (Windows Forms)
2. Back End - SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (FILESTREAM enabled to level 3)

I wanted to store the files (*.pdf, *.doc, *.exe, *.*) using the FILESTREAM feature in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I prefer FILESTREAM because sometimes the file size exceeds 2GB.

I'm able to save and retrieve file with FILESTREAM (using Windows Authentication/Integrated Security).

But my client wants to save or retrieve the file from different PC.

So I'm in need of accessing the FILESTREAM BLOB from remote systems.

Kindly help me to achieve my requirement.

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: "But my client wants to save or retrieve the file from different PC" - ?

Answer (score 2):

Read:

- [An Introduction To SQL Server FileStream](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)
- [FILESTREAM Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)

Like any other feature in SQL Server, once you've connected to the SQL Server from *any* machine, you can use its features. There's no difference between "local" and "remote" systems...... **all** client machines are "remote" as far as the SQL Server machine is concerned....